# Expression create a predicate with StartWith on Int32 field

Tags: c#, .net, expression, predicate

The expression builder below works fine. No problem if the `subMember` is a string.

Imagine now I receive a `subMember` named `Code`, this `Code` is an `Int32`. On this,
I'd like make a `StartWith` but I can't parse because it's an `Int32`. I think, I have to 
convert to a string. How can I implement that ?

Ex : 100, 102, 105, 200, 300, 301, 3011 ...

if subMember = "10", the result is 100,102,105

if subMember = "30", the result is 300,301,3011

if subMember = "301", the result is 301,3011

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(string member, object value)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression body = p;
    foreach (var subMember in member.Split('.'))
    {
        body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, subMember);
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(body, Expression.Constant(value, body.Type)), p);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `StartsWith` only really makes sense for strings, the first thing I would do would be to simplify things by using `string value`. Now, after the `foreach` loop to resolve the member, we can check the type of `body`:

```
if(body.Type != typeof(string)) body = Expression.Call(body, "ToString", null);
```

and then apply the `StartsWith`:

```
body = Expression.Call(body, "StartsWith", null, Expression.Constant(value));
```

then create the lambda:

```
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
```

However! If this is for LINQ-to-EF / LINQ-to-SQL, it will be dependent on the library supporting syntax such as:

```
.Where(x => x.Foo.Bar.ToString().StartsWith("1"))
```

since that is what is being constructed. Also, I would not expect this to work well with any database indexes; searching integers for those that *textually* begin with `"1"` is not an obvious index operation. Finally: watch out for negative numbers, etc; `-1` does not "start" with `"1"`.

Comment: I agree for the Code field type ... but sometimes I can't decide. About your solution the body look ok but there is an Exception on "StartWith" line : System.InvalidOperationException: No method 'StartsWith' on type 'System.String'

Comment: @Kris-I and what is `value` at this time? a string? an int? or...? (remember: I stated in the first paragraph that I was using `value` as a `string`)

Comment: the value is 10, I add a to string and look ok. Let's me try more

Comment: @Kris-I in which case you could perhaps just use `Expression.Constant(value.ToString())`